# Bootsy rails gem not showing images in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm using bootsy (https://github.com/volmer/bootsy) to make formatting my Blog article body much easier. When I upload files in the WYSIWYG editor locally I can view them later just fine; however, when I am in production and do this all the img tags link to

```
/uploads/bootsy/image/1/image_name.jpeg
```

Instead, the path should be a aws s3 url. I am using s3 with carrierwave = for some other things (the post main image url), and I'm not having any problems. I imagine there is some kind of config I need to do to work in production.

Comment: You will need to precompile the assets on production . Read on it here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: I thought precompling was only for assets that are in local app before I send to production. These assets are submitted through a form while in production.

Answer (score 0):

I solved part of the problem by creating an initializer for bootsy and adding:

```
Bootsy.setup do |config|
  config.storage = :aws
 config.store_dir = 'public/temp'
end
```

I'm not using the fog gem, instead I'm using carrierwave-aws gem. Also, when I my images are saved in my text field on my model, the url is also including some params. I also had to make sure the correct folder's permissions were public. This causes the images to break. I have to manually take out the params in my textarea in order to make this work.